# leaflet.js qgis2web popup in new window

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I am displaying a bunch of points on a map that have a field with an image name to popup when the point is clicked. The images are in a subfolder.

Is there an easy way to make the popup go to a new window with the target="_blank" tag?

I am using qgis2web, so I have this code snip to work with, it seems like this would be the right place to put a new window request, but instead I spawn a new tab for every feature in the map*

***code from qgis2web***

```
    var popupContent = '<table>\
            <tr>\
                <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Image'] !== null ? '<img width="300" src="images/' + String(feature.properties['Image']).replace(/[\\/:]/g, '_').trim() + '">' : '') + '</td>\
            </tr>\
        </table>';
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 100});
}
```

***end of qgis2web code***

*because this gets called  by the GeoJSON loader...

Comment: What do you mean by "make the popup go to a new window"? Can you clarify? Do you mean you want an image in the popup which is clickable? If so, what does it link to? Another URL?

Comment: It's simpler than that... Here's the desired behavior: When the user clicks a point that has a popup attached, instead of having a popup open, a new tab or window opens. The contents of the tab would be a .PNG image. The location and image name are stored in a field called Image.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Add a field to your layer for the filename (if you don't already have one)
2. Change that field's edit widget type to "Attachment" (QGIS3)/"Photo" (QGIS2)
3. If it was a new field, populate the rows with the image paths

Now, when you use qgis2web, your export should include the images which will then appear in your popups.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for answering! I have already gotten to the point you describe. But instead of having the images popup over the map (like a "popup") we would like to have the image open in a new tab that doesn't have the map in it. Just the raw .PNG file in a new tab.

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond the sphere of qgis2web, so I'm not the best person to answer. I can show you how to amend the qgis2web code so that you can click the image in the Leaflet popup, and it takes you to the raw image in a new tab/window, but that's not what you asked for.

Comment: I think what you describe is probably the solution. So I just need to wrap the img tag with an href tag with _target new, right? Something like this?  “<a href = 
‘<"images/' + String(feature.properties['Image']) + '">' : '') + ' target="_blank"> 
+
<img width="300" src="images/' + String(feature.properties['Image']) + '">' : '') + '
</a>

Comment: Something like `<td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Image'] !== null ? '<a href="images/' + String(feature.properties['Image']).replace(/[\\/:]/g, '_').trim() + '"><img width="300" src="images/' + String(feature.properties['Image']).replace(/[\\/:]/g, '_').trim() + '"></a>' : '') + '</td>\`